# Как убрать обратные слэши?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаюсь поднять приложение на hapi, но при запуске сервера вылазит такая ошибка.
Вроде как не хватает какого-то модуля, но повторная инициализация node не помогает, ещё какие-то странные слэши в пути к папкам, которых по факту нет. Думаю, в этом и есть причина ошибка. Подскажите, как это можно убрать и что к этому привело?

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module './C:\Users\dapro\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\testhapi\src/routes/\home.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\dapro\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\testhapi\src\server.js
- C:\Users\dapro\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\testhapi\server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at createServer (C:\Users\dapro\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\testhapi\src\server.js:22:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\dapro\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\testhapi\\src\\server.js',
    'C:\\Users\\dapro\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\testhapi\\server.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Странные слеши - экранирование символов. Следующие знаки в строке после `\` будут восприниматься как управляющая последовательность, поэтому, чтобы при выводе не возникало ошибок, строка с ними выводится именно так.

Проблема в том, что программа ищет модуль по *относительному* пути, а не *абсолютному*: `./` - эта запись означает, что следующий путь будет вычислен начиная с текущей директории, где у вас хранится исполняемый файл. Грубо говоря, вместо `./` будет подставлен путь к этой директории